# do i have to specify the database name in select statement while hosting?

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting an error while querying this select statement.

```
 $comments = dbgetvar("SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.approve = '1' AND c.spam = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS approved,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN c.approve = '0' AND c.spam = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN c.spam = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS spam,
                       COUNT(*) AS count
                       FROM COMMENTS c");
```

the above code works fine on my local machine using WAMP server. but when i host it in my server powered by cpanel it gives the following error.

> Notice: dbget: Table
>   'bhatkaln_test.COMMENTS' doesn't exist
>   in SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.approve =
>   '1' AND c.spam = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0
>   END) AS approved, SUM(CASE WHEN
>   c.approve = '0' AND c.spam = '0' THEN
>   1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending, SUM(CASE
>   WHEN c.spam = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
>   AS spam, COUNT(*) AS count FROM
>   COMMENTS c in
>   /home/bhatkaln/public_html/test/admin-login/models/validation.php
>   on line 154

what does the above error mean? in the database the comments table do exist.

Comment: Are your tables held in the `bhatkaln_test` database on your server?

Comment: means the table doesn't exist. You sure you've got the right database as daniel says?

Comment: @Thomas yes i am hundred percent sure it is their in my database.

Comment: in upper case and everything? Have you tried mysql_query?

Comment: yes i am using a user defined function dbgetvar for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing your server on Windows, where the table names are not case sensitive, since they ultimately refer to files.

When you upload to your Linux based server, the file system there *is* case sensitive. It doesn't work because you specify `COMMENTS` but the table name, presumably, is `comments`.

See [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) in the MySQL manual for more information.

Comment: correct. let me try this out. it might be of case sensitive problem.

Comment: problem solved. although i knew about this thing. it went unnoticed. thank you :)